# JavaScript change the text color

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors

I need your help. I have this javascript function to write a message to the logs. The logs text color is always blue. Anyone who can solve this issue? Below is my javascript code.

Thank you for your help.

```js
function logMessage(taskName,action,from,to) 
{
    var $logsDiv = jQuery("#logs");
    var message = '';
    if(action == "receive")
    {
       message = taskName +" was removed from '"+ from +"' and was added to '"+ to +"'<br/>";
       jQuery("#logs").css("color","blue");
       $logsDiv.append(message);
    }
    else
    {
      message = taskName +" was removed from '"+ from +"' and was added to '"+ to +"'<br/>";
      jQuery("#logs").css("color","green");
      $logsDiv.append(message);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
if(action == "receive")
{
   message = taskName +" was removed from '"+ from +"' and was added to '"+ to +"'<br/>";
   jQuery("<span>").css("color","blue").html(message).appendTo("#logs");
}
else
{
  message = taskName +" was removed from '"+ from +"' and was added to '"+ to +"'<br/>";
  jQuery("<span>").css("color","green").html(message).appendTo("#logs");
}
```

Comment: Use `<span/>` instead of `<span>` for IE compatibility.

Comment: it is now working. this is my div where the logs should be display`<div id="logs"></div>`. Should I put <span></span> inside?

Comment: Radu and Nittis, Now its working. I just mislook the remove function. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @justin If any of these answers correctly answered your question, you might want to [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, each time you add a new message, you also color your entire `#logs` instead of just the message. So instead of:

```js
jQuery("#logs").css("color","blue");
```

use something like:

```js
message = jQuery("<div/>").css("color","blue").append(message);
```